# access ARP header in socket buffer

Tags: c, linux-kernel

embedded system (kernel 2.4.20). In my driver I need to access ARP header fields, including MAC addresses; unfortunately in include/linux/if_arp.h those specific fields are commented . So I've tried to define my own 'arp_hdr' structure in my code with necessary fields:

```
struct arp_hdr {
    /* all the fields taken from include/linux/if_arp.h */
    /* and  additionaly these*/
   unsigned char       ar_sha[ETH_ALEN];
   unsigned char       ar_sip[4];
   unsigned char       ar_tha[ETH_ALEN];
   unsigned char       ar_tip[4];
}

int my_func(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct arp_hdr  *arph;

   arph = (struct arp_hdr *)skb->nh.raw;

  /* now print out the contents of the ARP header, but I get garbage */
}
```

Why do I get the garbage and what is the right way to do what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the hex dump of the ARP packet and also the garbage you get. (And btw what [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) precisely do you mean? There are many of them.) Without input it is very hard to know what (and where) you are doing wrong. Also I would have expected that `raw` actually points to the Ethernet header - ARP header follows it.

Comment: @Dummy00001: actually, nh stands for network header, ethernet headers are at mac.[ethernet|raw]

Comment: Before accesing sk_buff data, you should call pskb_may_pull() to make sure data is linearized: it can be on multiple buffers if your NIC supports scatter-gather IO.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I'm trying ARP described in RFC 826. According to include/linux/skbuff.h ARP belongs to network layer:

/* Network layer header */

union {

struct iphdr *iph;

struct ipv6hdr *ipv6h;

struct arphdr *arph;

struct ipxhdr *ipxh;

unsigned char *raw; } nh;